# how to set static frequency for intel pstate drivers?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am doing some research on frequency scaling and I need to run different experiments on different static frequencies.

I can easily map a static frequency by using acpi-cpufreq drivers, but I could not manage to set a static frequency to the new intel_pstate drivers. I tried changing `cpuinfo_min_freq` and `cpuinfo_max_freq` in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq` and also try to change it from `pstate-frequency -G -n` and `pstate-frequency -G -m`, but couldn’t manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually intel_pstates is a hardware governor, so it's not possible to select a precise frequency.

To set maximum and mininum value, I use the following command:

```
sudo cpufreq-set -g powersave
sudo cpufreq-set -u MAX_FREQ_VALUE
```